# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . AKA how to check for an Id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to know how to check for a CSS Id (or a class) if its enabled or disabled in jQuery. For example, let's say I have two Ids, sectionA and sectionB on some form pointing to two different sections of markup.
Now, I have a common reusable JS function that does some work based on which of the sections was referenced(activated) by the user. Think of user making entries on the some input fields of sectionA or viceversa. So I am trying to do something like this (please pardon my syntax):

```
function doSomething() { 
    if $('#sectionA').Enabled { //I know its not real syntax {
       var inp = document.getElementById('sectionA');
    }
    else if ('#sectionB').Enabled {
       var inp = document.getElementById('sectionB');
    }
}
```

etc.

Sorry if this is too trivial a question. I know the question is hard to visualize at first but I wish I could draw it out. I certainly appreciate any helpful hints.

Comment: What does "enabled" mean? And `$("#sectionA")` does pretty much the same thing as `getElementById("sectionA")` - there's no reason to use both.

Comment: " was referenced by the user." How, by clicking, focusing, ...? How is the title related, if you know the syntax is invalid?

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks for downvoting. Enabled: Think of a form using modals. Now the form has tow different sections A and B. User happens to see the same form with both sections on it but he will only enter input in either of the sections not both. Is it possible to control using some type of logic?

Comment: I didn't downvote. "sing modals"? What does that mean? I'm sorry but it's just not at all clear what you're talking about.

Comment: Also your code won't work but there's no syntax error in it. *edit* oh wait yes there is - you're missing `( )` for the `if` statement expressions.

Comment: edited, and sorry about the typo :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but usually you check the length of the jQuery object to detect, if it contains any elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery selectors us the same syntax as CSS does**, so you can just use the `:enabled` pseudo-class selector:

```
  if ($('#sectionA:enabled')) { ... }
```

But, after reading your comments, I'm not sure enabled is what you are looking for. You may want `:active`, which would be:

```
  if ($('#sectionA:active')) { ... }
```

You could also write both of these like this:

```
  if ($('#sectionA').is(':enabled')) { ... }
  if ($('#sectionA').is(':active')) { ... }
```

Also, if you are going to use jQuery, why not use it here as well:

```
  document.getElementById('sectionA')
```

Can just be:

```
  $('#sectionA')
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for understanding my question and the closest answer! exactly what I was looking for, put me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Shona No problem!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code  you  have  provided  has syntax errors like

```
.       else if ('#sectionB').Enabled
```

Should be

```
.       else if ($('#sectionB:enabled'))
```

Use brackets with if else conditions.. And Check the `$` sign there, also .Enabled is nothing in jQuery, if it's a check box then use `.prop('checked')` or .is(':enabled')

Comment: .prop('checked') doesn't tell you if the checkbox is enabled or active, only if it is checked, but it can be disabled and checked as well as inactive and checked.

Comment: You're right.. I thought that he just wanted to check if it's checked or not.. Thanks